# can't get virtual function of parent class to work

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a parent class with a virtual function in it, I then make a child class and define the function. I then make a vector of vectors and insert one of the child classes into it. I then try to call the virtual function and nothing outputs to the screen. I do not know why this is happening, does anyone know?

**Parent Class**

```
class insect{
        public:
           string type;
           int food_cost;
           int armor;
           int damage;
           insect();
           void set_food_cost(int x);
           void set_armor(int x);
           void set_damage(int x);
           virtual void attack(){} // this is the problematic function


};
```

**Child Class**

```
class bee: public insect{
        public:
           bee();
           int armor;
           int damage;
           void set_armor(int x);
           void attack();


};

void bee::attack(){
        cout << "im a bee, stab stab!\n";
}
```

**Creating Vector of Vectors**

```
vector< vector<insect> > insects_on_board(10);
```

**Adding a bee to the vector of vectors**

```
void add_bee(vector< vector<insect> > &insects_on_board, int &bees){
        bees++;
insects_on_board[9].push_back(bee());
}
```

**Function Call**

```
cout << "testing " << insects_on_board.at(9).at(0).type << endl;
        insects_on_board.at(9).at(0).attack();
```

**Output**

```
testing B
```

**My Question Again**

so in the output im expecting to see "testing B" and then "im a bee, stab stab!"

but only the "testing B" is outputted to the screen, any ideas why the other part is not?

Comment: You might want to search for 'slicing'

Comment: Your vector contains insects, not bees.

Comment: @Sneftel not a duplicate, first time asking this question

Comment: Apart from being a duplicate, this question also lacks a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene this is true, but bee is an insect, so anything an insect can do a bee should be able to do. and my vector at [0][9] is no longer an insect it should be a bee, which is proven when I test the type.

Comment: this is not a duplicate, once again this is not a duplicate...may be similar question but look at the code, totally different...plus that other question was asked 4 years ago

Comment: @billy Nowhere in your code do you test the type. And you don't need to test anything because you can just look at the declaration: `vector< vector<insect> >` says this is a vector of insects. Not bees.

Comment: @billy The code is doing exactly the same thing: putting a `Derived` into a container of `Base`s and expecting them to still be `Derived`s.

Comment: @melpomene I do test the type of insect in my code, right before I call the virtual function. and once again bee is derived from insect so it should have access to all of insects public functions.

Comment: This is a duplicate, once again this is a duplicate (by which I mean, don't bother repeating yourself, it doesn't help with anything). Look at the code: It has a `vector<BaseClass>` and OP expects to be able to call a virtual method in `DerivedClass` on it, but the `BaseClass` version is called. Exactly the same as yours. And what does it matter that someone else had your problem 4 years ago?

Comment: @billy `foo.type` accesses a member variable called `type`; it does not actually check the type. (And because your code is not a [mcve], we can't see how you set `type` anyway.) It doesn't matter what `bee` does or how it's derived; your code (at least the part you've shown us) uses objects of class `insect`, not `bee`.

Comment: @melpomene it matters because the person from 4 years ago wasn't dealing with what im currently dealing with

Comment: Please explain why you think that "*the person from 4 years ago wasn't dealing with what im currently dealing with*". You're kind of ignoring the part where I told you why we think it's the same problem: "*It has a `vector<BaseClass>` and OP expects to be able to call a virtual method in `DerivedClass` on it, but the `BaseClass` version is called.*". How is that not the same issue?

Comment: @melpomene im sorry for the confusion, ive added the add_bee function to my above code. im pretty sure im inserting bee objects into my vector, so why is the attack function not working?

Comment: Dude. All of that is answered in the duplicate question. In your particular code you're doing `.push_back(bee())`. `bee()` creates a `bee`, but `.push_back` takes an `insect`, so the `bee` object is implicitly converted to an `insect`, then copied to the vector (because you declared your vector as consisting of `insect` objects). It's a bit like doing `vector<int> v; v.push_back(sqrt(2.0));` and wondering why `v[0]` is just `1`.

Comment: @melpomene ok I understood that clearly, thank you. so I thought I was pushing a bee but really I was converting it into an insect. so how to fix this? hmmm, should I create a temp bee object and then push that into the vector? or would that just do the same thing? thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are storing actual `insect`s and not any `bee`s. Polymorphism (in its basic C++ way) works when you are doing 3 things:

1. Have a type hierarchy with properly defined and overridden `virtual` methods (like you are doing here,)
2. Create child instances (or a variety of parent and child instances,)
3. Access them through pointers (or references.)

You are missing points 2 and 3.

So, one way to fix it would be to store pointers to `insect`, and initialize them as either `bee`s or plain `insect`s, like so:

```
vector<vector<insect *>> insects_on_board (10, vector<insect *>(2)); // note the type
insects_on_board[9][0] = new bee;
insects_on_board[9][1] = new insect;

// Note the use of "->" instead of "."
cout << "testing " << insects_on_board[9][0]->type << endl;
insects_on_board[9][0]->attack();

// Contrast the output with the above's
cout << "testing " << insects_on_board[9][1]->type << endl;
insects_on_board[9][1]->attack();
```

**Update**:
Note that (at the basic level) any container that stores `insect`s by value cannot contain anything else; not even classes derived from `insect`. All the polymorphism and stuff you read and hear about is only applicable for **pointers** to parent and child types (or references to them.)

So, your `add_bee` function should look like this:

```
void add_bee (vector<vector<insect *>> & insects_on_board, int & bees) {
    bees++;
    insects_on_board[9].push_back(new bee());
}
```

I've made only two changes in there: the vectors now contain pointers to `insect` and I'm `new`ing the `bee`s.

Comment: ok ive added my add_bee function above, so I believe I was doing number 2 on your list. so is it just number 3 that is causing me problems?

Comment: @billy No, you were not. In `add_bee`, you are making a temporary `bee`, which is *casted* to an insect and pushed back into your vector. I'll update my answer.